# Maven - addjars-maven-plugin to add jars to classpath for an java project build

Tags: java, maven, jar, classpath

I am using `addjars-maven-plugin` to add all the jars present in `web-inf/lib` to my `classpath` and i am able to build my `web-application` and package it as `war`.

Is there any similar way to add all the jars present in `some folder` to `classpath`, while building `java classes` and package it as `jar`?

I tried the same plugin as below. But, when i try to build my project, the jars are downloaded to my `local repository`. But still i get class not found exception.

Kindly help. Thanks in advance!

```
    <build>
       <plugins>
                <plugin>
                  <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
                  <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0.2</version>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-jars</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/extlib</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

Full pom.xml content:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
   <artifactId>testlogger</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>1.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
              <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.2</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-jars</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/extlib</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I could achieve adding the jars present in any folder by using addjars-maven-plugin as above but, the only change i had to make is change the version of the plugin from 1.0.2 to 1.0.5. Thanks all for the support!!

Comment: What do you like to achieve? Cause the classpath is created by using maven-war-plugin ? What is the intention? Can you show your full pom file?

Comment: I have few dependent jars on which my java classes depend on. I do not want to use dependency tag to define my dependent jars. I found addjars-maven-plugin, which helped me to build my web app by adding all the jars in web-inf/lib to classpath. I need the similar thing to build my java project as well.

Comment: @khmarbaise i have added my pom.xml content in my question

Comment: The dependency is intended exactly for such purposes. It sounds like you are going the wrong path with Maven. For a web app you simply use maven-war-plugin by defining packaging war and that should solve it. I don't understand what's the purpose of this forlder src/main/extlib ? If those jars are created by maven use the repository otherwise install the artifacts and make you life easier.

Comment: Ok sorry i am very new to maven. So there is no similar plugin to build java project as how we have maven-war-plugin, for web application to add jars to classpath? So i will have to use dependency to define dependent jars. Is it?

Comment: I think the confusion is that a war is designed to be a collection of servlets and their dependent jars and template pages, but a jar is designed to be a discrete application or library.  You might be able to do what you want with the maven-shade-plugin (build an "uber-jar")

Comment: This plugin DOES  NOT WORK, at least not with mvnw.  Attempts to compile using mvnw fail because the jar file is not found in the repo. There appears to be no solution to the problem of using maven in Spring Boot with local files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge with `addjars-maven-plugin`. Calling `mvn clean install` it builds successfully but under eclipse (RAD 9.5) my source files could not be compiled because of missing jars. Now add the `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```
<build>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>${some.dir}/libs/*.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Nevertheless those jars are not added under `Maven Dependencies` in the project structure.

Comment: Is ${some.dir}  a full pathname? Is it a variable added to Eclipse? Is its root the root directory of the project? What is a good example of a value for ${some.dir}???